# Copying the jquery-ui accordion default example in local

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to copy the default [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#default) of jquery-ui accordion so I created this document below, but It doesn's show the content formatted with the jquery-ui css styles..any idea?

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo">

<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
        ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
        amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
        odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
        purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
        velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
        suscipit faucibus urna.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
        Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
        ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
        lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
        et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
        faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
        mauris vel est.
        </p>
        <p>
        Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
        Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
        inceptos himenaeos.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->

<div class="demo-description">
<p>
Click headers to expand/collapse content that is broken into logical sections, much like tabs.
Optionally, toggle sections open/closed on mouseover.
</p>
<p>
The underlying HTML markup is a series of headers (H3 tags) and content divs so the content is
usable without JavaScript.
</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing

```
$(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    });
```

working example http://jsfiddle.net/7LH3p/

Comment: Thanks I never expected that the styles depended on the accordion() function.

Comment: When using the accordion() function, some classes will be added to HTML elements :)

Answer (score 1):

your prob doesn't seems to be affected by the syntax error anywhere
and as you have copy pasted it , it certainly is free from any syntactical error i could find

, the only thing missing is that after inserting the .js files you also must call the jquery function as well

here is the syntax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#divElementId" ).accordion();
    });
</script>
```

now this applies the accordion function this particular div.

see , th .js libraries are only a collection of function bodies so inserting them only would not help ,
you need to call the function in your script tag

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by @AntonWestberg, you forgot the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No, it is on the jsfiddle link